# Can $\Phi$ be seen as a random variable here in this problem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that a particle is fired from the origin in the $(x,y)$-plane in a straight line in a direction at random angle $\Phi$ to the $x$-axis, and let $Y$ be the $y$-coordinate of the place where the particle hits the line ${x=1}$.

Can $\Phi$ bee seen as a random variable here? I want to think so but I'm not sure.

Comment: What hinders you from identifying $\Phi$ as a random variable?

Comment: Sure. If nothing is specified, you are probably intended to assume that $\Phi$ is uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,2\pi)$.  It may be useful to deal separately with positive and negative $Y$.

Comment: Yes in the next sentence after the last sentence it says that $\Phi$ is uniform in the interval $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$.

Comment: That is more sensible than my choice, though it makes no difference.